# How to skip a data set (on error) from TestNG data provider?

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to execute a data driven test using TestNG (& of course the dataprovider annotation).

My scenario is something like this ...

1. Use dataProvider to have a 2 dim array. (I am using this to read from Excel, but avoided it for brevity of the question).

   ```
   @DataProvider(name = "featureTest")
   public Object[][] dataSets() throws Exception {
       return new Object[][] { {"TC_01", "testuser_1", "Test@123", "ABC Street", "123-456-7899" }, 
                               { "TC_02", "testuser_1", "Test@123", "PQR Street", "222-456-7899" }
                              };
   }
   ```
2. In the @Test method, there are several methods as per the functional flow -

   ```
   @Test(dataProvider = "featureTest")
   public void executeTest(String... data) throws Exception {

        try{

            feature_1.execute(data);
            feature_2.execute(data);
            feature_3.execute(data);
            feature_4.execute(data);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Error has occured");
        }
   }
   ```

Now my main problem is that the functional error can occur anywhere out of these 4 (n) methods that I specify in my @Test.

**In case of an exception in any of the methods, I need to "Skip" the particular dataset and proceed to the next one.**
*For eg: In during execution of TC_01, an exception occured in feature_2.execute(), it should not execute the feature_3 and feature_4 methods.*

Note: 
I tried handling it using @BeforeMethod, @AfterMethod but still it goes through the unwanted methods that I want to avoid.

Thanks in advance for your help/inputs && apologies for the long question although a relatively simple concept to explain !!!

Comment: Please note, I have already tried using the SkipException (TestNG), but on a failure in TC_01 it skips TC_02 and other subsequent data sets. Also it doesn't serve the purpose of skipping the methods as explained above.

Comment: What do you have in your execute method?  Unless until you are catching your exceptions in there, what you are saying is not possible, that inspite of feature_2.execute(data); throwing an exception, feature_3 gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. Use return!

Use a condition or try catch to evaluate the failure and then use a return statement;

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is the factory approach,

Your testclass

```
class Test{
  Data data;
  Test(Data){
  this.data=data;
}


@Test
test1(){
  feature_1.execute(data);
}

@Test
test2(dependsOnMethods ="test1"){
  feature_2.execute(data);
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods ="test2")
test3(){
  feature_3.execute(data);
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods ="test3")
test4(){
  feature_4.execute(data);
}


}
```

And in your factory class

```
class Factory{

@Factory(DataProvider = "myDP")
public Object[] factoryTest(Data data){
    new Test(data);
}


@DataProvider
public Object [][] myDP(){

    enter code here
}

}
```

Comment: Although the factory approach is a good solution, but I don't want to change the existing pattern of coding for others and moreover it would be a tough ask to move all existing scripts with this approach. Was wondering if this can be handled within TestNG itself.